# Clearing a static list in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to clear a static list from my "playerStats" script which I use to access static variables globally. Adding elements to the list works just fine (with playerStats.myList.Add(levelNumber)), but when I try to use myList.Clear I get this error:

*"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"*.

Here is the relevant code: First the list definition inside the playerStats class:

```
{

    public static List<int> myList = new List<int>();

}
```

And this is then on another script referencing the playerStats:

```
public void goBack()
    {

        playerStats.myList.Clear;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

    }
```

Why can't I clear the list like this?

Comment: You need `()` after `.Clear();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error essentially says that you are taking a reference to a method, but you are not assigning it to anything that can reference it. The compiler doesn't know you are actually trying to call this method.

You need to add parentheses, as in

```
playerStats.myList.Clear();
```

to call the method.

Comment: Thank you! I could swear I tried that too at one point but now it indeed worked! Thanks again!

Comment: @user44109 then can you accept my answer? mark the check mark near the answer.